# Add local controller property to store models

Tags: ember.js

I want to add a simple 'selected' property to store objects, just localised to the particular route/controller.

So in my controller I'm loading the 'groups' from the store. For each 'group' I want to add in a 'selected' property. Tried a few different approaches but just can't get it working.

Advice on "the ember way" would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

If what you're trying to do is display something different for each group that isSelected. I'd take the following approach:

I'd create an array on your controller of selectedGroups, which can either be an array of group objects from the store or just simply an array of ids. As a group is selected/unselected, it can be added to/removed from the array. You can then use a computed function or pass selectedGroups into components to do whatever you need with selectedGroups.

So, if you had your groups template like so:

```
{{#each model as |group|}}
  {{my-item-component item=group selectedItems=selectedGroups}}
{{/each}}
```

Then in your `my-item-component.js`, you would have a computed function like:

```
isSelected: computed('item', 'selectedItems.[]', function () {
   // This assumes selectedItems contains item/group objects rather
   // than ids. You will need to tweak a little for ids.
   return (this.get('selectedItems').indexOf(this.get('item')) !== -1);
})
```